# PasswordDeriveBytes function

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I am using AES (Rijndael) symmetric-key algorithm to encrypt-decrypt data.
I am using the System.Security.Cryptography. PasswordDeriveBytes function;

```
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
                                                        passPhrase,
                                                        saltValueBytes,
                                                        hashAlgorithm,
                                                        passwordIterations);
```

Looking this function up on MSDN etc, it does not tell you explicitly what parameters ‘hashAlgoritm’ can take.
There are examples on the internet of it taking SHA1 as well as SHA256. I experimented with this and found that it can take SHA512.
But without documentation, I have no idea if SHA512 is really better than SHA256 or SHA1 or even MD5.
Can anybody shed light on this issue?

Comment: MD5 was broken years ago, so don't use that one!

Comment: PasswordDerivedBytes just generates a session key derived from a hash.  Pick an algorithm that is currently not known to be insecure in some way.

Comment: @PeterRichie disagree, KDF have other security requirements

Comment: @PeterRitchie Password hashes and general purpose hashes are very different. So that other question is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: @ColinMackay Collision resistance isn't really important for password hashing. While I wouldn't use MD5 or SHA-1, there are no meaningful attacks against either when used as building block in PBKDF2 while hashing passwords.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Huh? both questions deal with cryptographic hashing.  They both ask which asking algo is better...

Comment: @PeterRitchie This one talks about a password hash. All the answers to the other question deal with general purpose hashes. For example plain SHA-2 is a horrible password hash, but a good general purpose hash. On the other hand MD5 is a broken general purpose hash, but it's okay when used in PBKDF2 for password hashing. And bcrypt is only a password hash, not not a general purpose hash at all.

Comment: @CodesInChaos References?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23116/md5-collision-attacks-are-they-relevant-in-password-hashing

Comment: @CodesInChaos wow, my answer nicely mimicked Thomas answer, but that answer has just **a tiny bit** more meat on it :P

Answer (score 3):

The security of the hash method is slightly less important for a key derivation function. It's probably best to choose one that matches the required key size, although use of MD5 in general should be discouraged. Other applications may only use SHA-1 .

Note that `PasswordDeriveBytes` has been deprecated and should certainly not be used for output larger than the hash size. Use PBKDF2 istead, see [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).

Comment: Do you have a reference to back up that the security of a hash algorithm is less important for key derivation?

Comment: @PeterRitchie 1) A random unpredictable salt blocks many attacks, such as collisions against MD5. To find collisions with a random salt is a form of universal multi-collision, which is *much* harder to achieve. 2) Collisions are irrelevant. An attacker being able to find two passwords with the same hash is useless. That'd allow him to use two different passwords to log into his own account, but it in no way allows him to break another account.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Salting is not algorithm specific.

Comment: @PeterRitchie The security of the hash is still essential: lack of first pre-image resistance would be a major attack against a password hash. And then there is a property a password hash should have, but a general purpose hash should not: Being expensive to compute, which slows down brute-force attacks. This compensates for the low entropy of typical passwords.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Salting prevents collisions regardless of algo.  If you salt regardless of algo then it gets right back to which algo is more secure.  So, you haven't answered why security of the hash algo is less important for password hashing...

Comment: @PeterRitchie Since password hashing only requires first pre-image resistance, many otherwise broken algorithms (such as MD5) don't cause any problems. Other questions, such as which constructions work well on standard computers but not well on GPUs and ASIC are far more important than the strength differences between MD5 and SHA-2.

Comment: @CodesInChaos you're basically saying the hash doesn't matter as long as you salt.  There are many references that suggest the hash algorithm is equality (sometimes more) important, like http://bit.ly/WeOeTx , http://bit.ly/Yt6XqU , http://bit.ly/Yt7mJT etc.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for the edit, I was using my smartphone, which lacks the '`' character. Major nuisance, time to switch to a Cyranogen mod or at least another keyboard.

Comment: @PeterRitchie My point is that the security differences between MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-2 have little effect on the strength of the password hash. What matters are the relative efficiencies of them on CPU vs. GPU/FPGA/ASIC. For example the main reason why PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 is better than PBKDF2-HMAC-MD5 is because SHA512 uses 64 bit arithmetic, not because it's a strong hash.

Comment: @owlstead I think vanilla android 2.3 hash backticks: first [?123] and then [alt] will show backticks as second symbol in the first row.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've provided three references that say different, again, do you have any references to back up your position?